# php cURL set manual cookies

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I have a cookie file with this

```
.adidas.de  TRUE    /   FALSE   1519852113  restoreBasketUrl    %2Fon%2Fdemandware.store%2FSites-adidas-DE-Site%2Fde_DE%2FCart-UpdateItems%3Fpid_0%3DBB2092_610%26qty_0%3D1
.adidas.de  TRUE    /   FALSE   1550524169  utag_main   v_id:015fe2df50a60014c3cedb252f0d04073001906b01978$_sn:7$_ss:0$_st:1518989969891$_prevpage:ACCOUNT%7COVERVIEW%3Bexp-1518991769885$_pn:3%3Bexp-session$ses_id:1518987220846%3Bexp-session$ab__doubleclick:TEST%3Bexp-1521580164884
```

I know I can read it out from file in cURL like

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiefile);
```

But how can I set these cookies manual without a file? Because I need to modify them a bit before sending

Answer (score 1):

You can use `curl_setopt` function with option `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["Cookie: mycookie=value;mycookie2=value2"]);
```

---

**[Edit]**

From this guide [The Unofficial Cookie FAQ](http://www.cookiecentral.com/faq/).

The layout of Netscape's cookies.txt file is such that each line contains one name-value pair. An example cookies.txt file may have an entry that looks like this:

```
.netscape.com TRUE / FALSE 946684799 NETSCAPE_ID 100103
```

Each line represents a single piece of stored information. A tab is inserted between each of the fields.

From left-to-right, here is what each field represents:

**domain** - The domain that created AND that can read the variable.

**flag** - A TRUE/FALSE value indicating if all machines within a given domain can access the variable. This value is set automatically by the browser, depending on the value you set for domain.

**path** - The path within the domain that the variable is valid for.

**secure** - A TRUE/FALSE value indicating if a secure connection with the domain is needed to access the variable.

**expiration** - The UNIX time that the variable will expire on. UNIX time is defined as the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970 00:00:00 GMT.

**name** - The name of the variable.

**value** - The value of the variable.

---

***For answer your question***

**1)** To modify a bit before sending do this:

```
$file = file('cookie.txt');
$cookies = [];
/*
 * From the guidelines that I linked and posted above each line must contain 7 "fields" separated by tab only (The text you posted in the question is not well formatted but with some tricks we can do this)
 */
foreach ($file as $fileLine) {
    $fileLine = preg_replace("/\s+/", "\t", trim($fileLine));
    $fields = explode("\t", $fileLine);
    if (count($fields) === 7) {
        $cookies[] = [
            'domain' => $fields[0],
            'flag' => $fields[1],
            'path' => $fields[2],
            'secure' => $fields[3],
            'expiration' => $fields[4],
            'name' => $fields[5],
            'value' => $fields[6],
        ];
    }
}

var_dump($cookies); // Here you have all lines from your cookie file and can modify the fields such name, value or something
```

---

**2)** For override the `cookie.txt` with your modify cookies array do this:

```
// Preserve Netscape format
$cookies = implode(PHP_EOL, array_map(function($data){
    return implode("\t", $data);
}, $cookies));

file_put_contents('cookie.txt', $cookies);
```

---

**3)** For send your new cookies from file do this (must be in Netscape format):

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
```

Comment: Yes, but how can I convert those cookies I sent in my question to this CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER? Can you help me?

Comment: Hi @derk11992 i just edited the answer. I hope this is enough. Try and after say me something XD